# C++ template constructor ambiguity used when it shouldn't

Tags: c++, class, templates, constructor, compiler-errors

I have got an issue because when instantiating a class object, the implementation is using the wrong constructor obtained through a template rather than the suitable one.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

`dummy.h`

```
#ifndef GUARD_dummy
#define GUARD_dummy

#include <vector>

class Dummy {

    public:
        Dummy() {}
        explicit Dummy(std::vector<int>::size_type n, const int& val = 0): data(n, val) {}
        template <class In>
            Dummy(In b, In e) { create(b, e); }
    private:
        std::vector<int> data;

        template <class In>
            void create(In, In);
};

template <class In>
    void Dummy::create(In b, In e) {
        std::copy(b, e, std::back_inserter(data));
    }

#endif
```

`test.cpp`

```
#include "dummy.h"

int main() {
    Dummy v(3, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

I expect the constructor `Dummy(size_type, const int&)` to be used.
Why is it not happening?
In which ways can I overcome this issue?

Thank you!

### SOLUTION

```
#include "dummy.h"

int main() {
    const size_t dim = 3;
    Dummy v(dim, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

### New question

If let's say I had defined the constructor as `Dummy(int, const int&)`. In that case, would the code be wrong? Should I delete one of the constructors to solve ambiguity?

Thanks again!

Comment: Don't create overloads with confusingly similar signatures, and you won't be confused when the wrong one inevitably gets picked.

Answer (score 3):

The constant `3` will naturally evaluate as int. It needs to be converted to `size_type` to use the first constructor. For any overloaded function, including constructors, the one requiring the fewest conversions will be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "dummy.h"

int main() {
    int four = 4;
    Dummy v( static_cast<size_t>(3), four);
    return 0;
}
```

The C++ automatic type conversions were not finding your template specialization from the types you provided in the ctor where were signed int types by default.

Comment: There is no declared specialization in the code. And the types aren't `int` "by default". The type of `3` and of `4` simply _is_ `int`. Both overloads of the constructor are also viable in either case. Only the specific rules with which overload resolution chooses the preferred overload give different results depending on whether you use `int`/`int` or `size_t`/`int` as argument types.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already explained the problem. But to solve your issue in a more solid way, you should make sure the templated constructor is only available for iterator-like types.

I don't know what c++ version you're using, but in cpp17 you could check for existence of operator* via sfinae, and in cpp20 you could simply use a concept. Then the templated ctor will only ever be picked for iterators.